# Why does Windows Explorer change the 'Folder Modify Time' when first accessing a folder after a robocopy?

Tags: windows-explorer, file-transfer, robocopy

I am attempting to use Robocopy to mirror a directory structure (`/e`) and keep created/modified/accessed times.  This should be fairly simple with '`/copy:DAT /dcopy:DAT`' and appears to preserve the file and directory times as expected.

The problem is, the first time I open a folder in explorer after robocopy finishes, the 'modified' time changes to the the current time.  Subsequent accesses do not show this behavior.

What could be causing this behavior?